# PDF of difference of Beta$(1, n)$ and Beta$(n, 1) =$ Beta(n - 1, 2)

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, beta-function

Given $X_1 \sim \text{Beta}(1, n)$ and $X_2 \sim \text{Beta}(n, 1)$, how do I show that $X_2 - X_1 \sim \text{Beta}(n - 1, 2)$?

I have seen a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1825768/pdf-of-the-difference-between-two-independent-beta-random-variables), but that was not particularly helpful.

Comment: The difference of two independent random variables with values in $(0,1)$, takes values in $(-1,1)$. As such, it is not Beta.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer. The distribution of $Y = X_2 - X_1$ is **not** going to be $Beta(n-1, 2)$. For starters the support of the Beta distribution is in the interval (0,1), and $Y < 0$ with nonzero probability.

This may be true, however, when $n \rightarrow \infty$. Here is a quick simulation which illustrates this point. Note that even in the bottom panel, where $n=10$, the minimum of the simulated $Y$ values is $-0.1$ illustrating that this is NOT a beta distribution.
[image]

You are somewhat misunderstanding the link you refer to in your comment. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, and have the distributions you state, then they will not be independent (see above figures).

If however, $U_1, \cdots U_n$ are iid $U(0,1)$ observations, and we let $X_2 = \max(U_i)$ and $X_1 = \min(U_i)$ then marginally the distributions of $X_1$ and $X_2$ will be what you state. In this case, $X_2 - X_1$ will follow the desired distribution, but they key point is that they are not independent. Namely, $X_2$ must be at least as big as $X_1$, so that the difference will always be between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I found a [link](https://mathoverflow.net/a/51248), which claims the same thing as what I am claiming in the original question.

Comment: I understand now... You are misunderstanding the claim. If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, then this is NOT true. See the figure in my answer to see this. The link you refer to is saying that, if $U_1, \cdots U_n$ are iid $U(0,1)$ random variables, then the distribution of $\max(U) - \min(U) \sim Be(n-1, 2)$. Although marginally, $\max(U_i)$ and $\min(U,i)$ have the distributions you state in your question, they are not independent. For instance $\max(U_i)$ will always be greater than $\min(U_i)$.